# Is it possible to get the parameter args as a single list for a deffunction?

Tags: clips

I'd like to write a function `all-neq` that is like the builtin `neq` except that it also enforces that no two elements can be the same (instead of only the first one being different than the rest).

So while the output of `(neq 3 4 5 5)` is TRUE, I want `(all-neq 3 4 5 5)` to be FALSE, since there are two 5's.

Here's what I've tried, but I keep getting an error regarding the parameter list as an input.

```
(deffunction all-neq ?args
  (foreach ?arg1 ?args
    (foreach ?arg2 ?args
      (if (and (not (eq ?arg1-index ?arg2-index))
               (eq ?arg1 ?arg2)) then
          (return FALSE))))
  (return TRUE))
```

Error message for this one is:

```
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for parameter list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard parameter to group all of the remaining arguments of a deffunction into a single multifield value:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction all-neq ($?args)
  (foreach ?arg1 ?args
    (foreach ?arg2 ?args
      (if (and (not (eq ?arg1-index ?arg2-index))
               (eq ?arg1 ?arg2)) then
          (return FALSE))))
  (return TRUE))
CLIPS> (all-neq 3 4 5 5)
FALSE
CLIPS> (all-neq 3 4 5 6)
TRUE
CLIPS>
```

This will also collapse all multifield values into a single multifield value, so you won't get the correct behavior when comparing multifield values:

```
CLIPS> (all-neq (create$ 3 4) (create$ 5 5))
FALSE
CLIPS>
```

In order to get the correct behavior for multifield values, you'd need to create a user-defined function in C as described in the Advanced Programming Guide rather than using a deffunction.